# Android Notifications, loads only the latest intent when there are more than one notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an app which has 4 layers/stack, something like,

> HomePage >> DetailPage >> MapPage >> ChatPage

I managed to create notifications whenever I received different chat messages (note that each conversation has its unique id, say **ChatId**)

for different conversation, I will create a notification using **ChatId** as the ***requestCode*** in the pendingIntent

The problem I am facing is that, whenever I received more than 1 notification, say **ChatId1** comes first, followed by **ChatId2**. Then when I clicked on the **ChatId1**'s notification, it will launch the latest intent which is **ChatId2**, making the conversations loaded in **ChatPage** are conversations of **ChatId2**.

Question is, how can I make it so that, when I clicked on **ChatId1**'s notification, it loads messages of **ChatId1**, and when click on **ChatId2**, it loads messages of **ChatId2**.

Below is the snippet of the code where I create my notifications

```
public void createLocalNotification(String meetingIdLong, String countryCode, String phoneNumber, String contactName, String chatMessage) {

            // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
            // notification is selected
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatLog.class);
            long L = Long.parseLong(meetingIdLong);
            int a = Integer.parseInt(meetingIdLong);
            intent.putExtra("meetingId", L);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);

            Intent intent2= new Intent(this, MeetingDetailPage.class);
            intent2.putExtra("meetingId", L);
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, MapPage.class);
            intent3.putExtra("meetingId", L);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatLog.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent2);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent3);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

            PendingIntent pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(a, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            String notificationSound = _defPrefs.getString("pref_notification_tone", "");

            NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(contactName)
            .setContentText(chatMessage)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_smallicon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.noti_smallicon))
            .setSound(Uri.parse(notificationSound))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setNumber(++numberMsg)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            String[] events = new String[6];
            events [numberMsg - 1] = new String(chatMessage);

            // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(contactName);
            inboxStyle.setSummaryText(numberMsg + " new message(s)");

            for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

                inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
            }
            noti.setStyle(inboxStyle);

            String isChatOpen, isChatOpenId;

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            isChatOpen = preferences.getString("isChatOpen","");
            isChatOpenId = preferences.getString("isChatOpenId","0");

            if (!isChatOpenId.equals(meetingIdLong))
            {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(a, noti.build());
            }

         }
```

Comment: The id that is passed for each notification needs to be unique in order to start multiple notification intents, else the latest one will overwrite the others

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille yes, the chatId that I am passing is unique, I am able to receive multiple notifications, just that, when I click on chatid 1's notification, the latest intent which is from chat id 2 was eventually called.

Comment: may be you could differentiate it using the id itself? like pass the unique id, and then in the activity based on the id received display concerned data

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

for each your Intent you want to be unique. Its just a dummy action, but it helps.